# Force Developers to add comments in function

Tags: typescript, tslint, tsconfig

I know it must be a simple question. But I tried hard googling around this but couldn't find a single suitable result. I'm managing a big team with large number of people working under me. I want to make sure that, every single function written by my developers should have a comment before it. It makes sense to add the rule in my tslint file.

> How do I enforce my developers to add comment before function begins (like below)?

```
/**
* This function returns a string hello
* @author Sahil Purav
*/
myfunction(): string {
   return 'hello';
}
```

Comment: Add code review to the process along with coding standards

Comment: there is already issue open  at https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/623

Comment: It's there... But we are working in automated world. Isn't it good to have tslint rule so that, even before it comes to a code review, we will have comments on function so that, a reviewer will concentrate more on the logic written by a developer not the missing standard.

Comment: After a while the coding standard will be second nature to both the coder and reviewer

Comment: While a technical approach is no doubt enforceable - as @Ed suggests - guidelines and encouraging people by demonstrating the benefits of writing good comments needs to be done anyway. Before that, you can expect people to get around the technical requirements by writing any tosh into the comment just to get the system to stop complaining - and that's arguable worse than if they just hadn't commented it... (and maintenance wise - someone will have to come fix the comment later (or more likely - forget to do so and it'll just hang around for ages))

Comment: I agree with you @JonClements. But we've a process of running lint before pushing the code on staging server. If tslint fails, then the code will not be pulled on server. In that case, developer will have to add comments. Also, if we've comments over the function, it really doesn't harm. I would still go with the phrase "something is better than nothing"

Comment: @Sahil suppose you can take that approach - in my experience though - "nothing is better than something misleading/inaccurate/just noise"...

Answer (score 1):

I did some more research on this and found that, there is a rule in tslint to enforce comments and good thing, it is highly configurable.

I used following rule which suffice my requirement:

```
"completed-docs": [
      true,
      {
        "enums": true,
        "functions": {
          "visibilities": ["exported"]
        },
        "methods": {
          "location": "instance",
          "privacies": ["public", "protected"]
        }
      }
    ]
```

For more information check this - https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/completed-docs/